# Onpremise SSAS Cube Credential refresh issue

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-data-explorer

We have created SSAS cube connected to Azure Data Explorer using .Net Framework Data Provider For SQL Server. We are using OAuth2 to authenticate data-source.
We have configured SQL Server Job to automatically process cube using below command

```
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "CubeName"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Our issue is, because authentication type is oAuth2 it generates token to authenticate ADX cluster and token expires after 1 hour. So our Automated job fails if token expires. Is there any automated way we can refresh credential before start processing cube. We know there is manually way we can Refresh Credential as show below: we need to replicate this functionality in automated way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this problem also with SQL Azure or only with ADX?

ADX does not close TDS connection after token associated with it expires. This was recently fixed and the fix will be deployed to all ADX cluster in 2 weeks.

Comment: Yes we have this problem with SQL Azure too. We are trying to find a way to generate refreshtoken and accesstoken and trying to refresh credential using SQL Server agent job.